# less.js not working in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, less

I noticed that [less.js](http://fadeyev.net/2010/06/19/lessjs-will-obsolete-css/) is working in firefox but not in Chrome, or is it because I made an error?

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" href="css/style.less" />
<script src="http://lesscss.googlecode.com/files/less-1.0.21.min.js"></script>

@highlight: #cb1e16;
@shade1: #cb1e16;
@tone1: #5c6f7d;
@grad1: #e6edf3;
@grad2: #8a8d92;
@text1: #333e44;

header, footer, section, article, nav, aside { display: block; }

.grad {
  background: @grad2;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, @grad1, @grad2 1200px);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 1200, from(#e6edf3), to(#8a8d92));
}

html {
  .grad;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

even if i try `html { background: red; }` it still does not work in chrome am i making a mistake somewhere?

Comment: Is your CSS not meant to be in a <style> tags, even if less.js is going to mess around with it?

Comment: no, its a link to the css or (.less file) [less.js info](http://fadeyev.net/2010/06/19/lessjs-will-obsolete-css/)

Comment: I checked your code in both, Firefox and Chrome, both up to date and in both it is working; the only thing I noticed, in Chrome your background gradient is inverted. 

Which versions do you use?

Comment: oh yes, i had that prob also, its because i got the syntax wrong, u shld use `background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 1200, from(#e6edf3), to(#8a8d92));`

Comment: On a note for anyone else ending up here: I've gotten the same error on my web host's web server. It was erroneously sending empty responses because the `.less` file/mime type was unknown. Configuring the web server to properly serve .less files fixed it. (It was not a cross-domain request, all `.js`/`.less` files were served from the same folder.)

Comment: related http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/50006/chrome-refused-to-execute-this-javascript-file

Answer (score 62, accepted):

From the link you provided : **Less.js browser script currently won’t work if you’re using Chrome and the path to your page starts with “file:///” due to a known Chrome issue.**

Comment: This apparently effects Safari 6.0 (8536.25) as well.

Comment: Can this be solved by using --disable-web-security & -–allow-file-access-from-files ? EDIT: Nevermind, tried it with those parameters and it works. Ugh ! Should've read 2 rows lower :)))

Comment: This answer would have been better if it included at least one possible workaround for the problem!

Answer (score 50):

Lithium is correct, there is a known Chrome issue with loading local javascript files. This is a security "feature" in Chrome. There are two workarounds that I know of:

1. Develop your local projects with a web server. You can install and use Apache very easily, though configuring takes some patience. If you are on Windows, you may be able to install IIS.  When you do this, instead of double-clicking an HTML file, you will browse to it from http://localhost/
2. Add the command-line switch `-allow-file-access-from-files` to your shortcut and Chrome will allow you to load LESS.JS without a fuss.

I'm tempted to mention using a different version of the less converter, like the ruby `lessc` version, or one of the ports to PHP or .NET, but less.js is more current, and I think you should keep with it.

Comment: Amit - try http://superuser.com/questions/16750/how-can-i-run-an-application-with-command-line-arguments-in-mac-os

Comment: The easiest way that I know of to start a local web server is to do python -m SimpleHTTPServer in your site's root.

Comment: I, too, recommend using a local web server. Try [tag:node.js] and the [Connect library's `.static()` method](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/static.html) as a [simple dev web server for static material](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8427954) to be able to use less.js (and avoid any other potential `file:///` weirdness).

Comment: yess adding switch to shortcut worked: create a new shortcut in Windows, right click -> Properties and set its target to : `chrome.exe -allow-file-access-from-files`, was a quick fix, but still web-server recommended

Answer (score 14):

In case anybody else ever needs a quick solution for this on Mac OS X (tested on Lion)

**"Walkthrough for dummies"**

---

---

**Special thx** to [Lithium](https://stackoverflow.com/users/290769/lithium), [Nathan Strutz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5918/nathan-strutz) + the guys from [this post on Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/16750/how-can-i-run-an-application-with-command-line-arguments-in-mac-os)

---

---

**Create an AppleScript**

[image: Apple Script Editor]

**with following command**

---

```
do shell script "/Applications/Google\\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\\ Chrome-allow-file-access-from-files"
```

---

[image: AppleScript]

**Then save as Application**

[image: save as Application]

(*I put this into my dock and added an alternative Chrome icon for fast access*)

[image: add to Dock]

**IMPORTANT:** Chrome needs to be closed in order for this *script(App)* to work.

Comment: I keep getting Syntax Error: Expected “"” but found unknown token. Any ideas??

Comment: The backslashes should be escaped. Should be `do shell script "/Applications/Google\\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\\ Chrome -allow-file-access-from-files"`

Answer (score 3):

Actually, contrary to the accepted answer this does work fine. I'm on Chrome 19, Mac OS X, context is a Chrome extension. I experienced the same issue. I started to experiment with different ways to include it, switching out text in the rel, type, href and so on.

**This works, the key is href="css/styles.css (use .css, not .less):**

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />
<script src="libs/less-1.3.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Styles are nicely applied and the JavaScript console in Chrome has the following to say (slightly stripped for clarity):

```
less: parsed /css/styles.css successfully. less-1.3.0.min.js:8
less: css generated in 33ms
```

I know one aren't supposed to use compiled CSS client side, but in the context of a Chrome Extension there is no alternative other than regular CSS (eww). You can't request the stylesheet from a server either because the client will be offline every now and then.

Comment: `Uncaught Error: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101` for me. :(

Comment: How do you get that verbosity from less?

Comment: I got the verbosity automatically when Less was included client-side. It might have been removed in a later version of Less? (Haven't tested.)

Comment: Yes, it did worked for me too, but it is not compiled by less. How and where did you got this

Answer (score 3):

**I recommend you to use a compiled vesion** of the LESS file. You can do this for example in windows with WinLess or SimpLESS.

I'm using winless. It automatically compiles my .css files when I save my code.

You also need to run your example on a webserver like IIS / tomcat / Jboss

I hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Editing the link tag to something like this will make it work with any browser **ONLY** if you are not using Less syntax within the file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/less" href="css/styles.less" />
```

So why would you use a plain css in a less file? No idea, but just so you know.

Answer (score 0):

I found this small app to be very useful to circumvent the file:// problem: Anvil for Mac. One minute and it's upp and running as many sites as you like through URL's like http://myapp.dev.

http://anvilformac.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use  -allow-file-access-from-files , or run wamp, lamp, or etc. you can use this extension it helped me  a lot.
 [the link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb?hl=en)