# WebStorm: HTTP server options locally and cross platform

Tags: node.js, angularjs, webserver, webstorm

I have just downloaded WebStorm 5.0 for testing with AngularJS, and I have a problem. I can't seem to figure out how to configure or add a server for my HTTP files.

I am currently using a Windows 7 PC but I am also using a Mac.

I would like to know how I configure a web server in WebStorm. It seems it might be something to do with Run Configurations, but I have 2 options under JavaScript debug which are Local / Remote and then node and other things like that.

So I am little confused, does WebStorm not come with its own internal server?

Of course I have IIS installed on my PC but not available for the Mac, I was wondering if there was a built in server that was compatible with both or if something like that existed. Using Tomcat I think is overkill as I only require client hosting - i.e. no Java.

I also hear a lot of talk about NodeJS, is it possible to host my WebStorm project locally in a NodeJS server? Unsure where to start here.

Any help would really be grateful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE**: Built-in HTTP server [is available](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2013/03/webstorm-6-0-released-adds-typescript-debugging-with-source-maps-fresh-ui-and-much-more/) since WebStorm 6.0.

---

WebStorm doesn't come with any HTTP server, you need to install/configure it yourself. There is a [guide for JavaScript debugging on Windows](http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Remote_JavaScript_debugging_with_WebStorm_and_PHPStorm). On Mac you can use Apache or any other server.

It should be possible to use Node.js to run a simple HTTP server: [Using node.js as a simple web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084360/node-js-as-a-simple-web-server).

Comment: When Python 2.4+ installed: `python -m SimpleHTTPServer [port]`

Comment: Update: WebStorm 6.0 now includes a built-in HTTP server, which should work for your needs.