# execute javascript from html - node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I hava an html file that execute js file inside.
Now I want to run this with Node.js server.
I can see that it write the html file in it (it write 'hi (:') but ignored the js file.

this is the 'server.js' file:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
var content;
//read the file
fs.readFile('index.html', function read(err, html) {
    if (err)
    {
        throw err;
    }

    content = html;

http.createServer(function(request,response)
{
    response.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    response.write(html);
    response.end();
}).listen(8081);

console.log("listening on port 8081");
});
```

and this is the 'index.html' file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"> </script>
        <script> </script>
        </head>
    <body>
        <div id="empty">
            hi :)
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for your help! (:

Comment: Did you take a look at this thread ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084360/node-js-as-a-simple-web-server

Comment: missing a 'server' to serve the `script.js` from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've created a server that responds to every single request with the contents of `index.html`--so when the `<script>` tag asks the server for the `script.js` file, the server incorrectly sends it `index.html` again.

In your `createServer` handler, you'll want to look at the incoming request and figure out which file the request is asking for, and send different data back accordingly.

To handle this situation more robustly, where you don't have to have an `if` statement for every file you might want to send, you can use an abstraction over your `createServer` handler to detect and send static files automatically. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084360/node-js-as-a-simple-web-server) contains several solutions that may help put you on the right track.