# node.js http opening static textfiles in browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, text-files

If i have a httpserver in node.js that is serving a website on port 3000.

```
var httpserver = http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index.html');
});
```

I need to access a txt file located at /public/

If i for example do localhost:3000/other_site.html, if this other_site.html is in /public/ it opens it, but if the file is txt it doesn't open it.

Is there a solution to this without having to install http-request, connect or other npm modules?

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use express? If yes,

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
```

makes the trick.

If not, try searching the archives :) [Using node.js as a simple web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084360/using-node-js-as-a-simple-web-server)

Comment: i use express. i added what you suggested. When calling http://localhost:3000/draw.txt i am still getting a "Cannot GET /draw.txt"

Comment: try /public/draw.txt ?

Comment: Cannot GET /public/draw.txt

Comment: Is the file draw.txt actually in the public folder...?

Answer (score 0):

What error you are getting ?

```
if you experiencing browser error, try sending response header and set Content Type text/html and retry
```

Example code

```
 fs.readFile('myfile.txt', function(error, file) {
        response.writeHead(200, {'content-type':'text/html'});
        response.end();
    });
```