# Simple static node.js http server in the cloud

Tags: node.js, httpserver, digital-ocean

I've spun up a Digital Ocean server, and I'm trying to serve a simple static web page. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23122981/1920325) answer recommended I use the [http-server](https://www.npmjs.org/package/http-server) package. I can start serving on `http://localhost:8080` by simply running:

```
http-server
```

Neat. How do I actually serve the page up remotely though, so that I'd be able to access it on my desktop by using the external IP of the server, for example, `http://139.32.5.6`?

This is probably a really silly question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [http-server readme](https://github.com/nodeapps/http-server#available-options), the address to listen on defaults to `0.0.0.0`, so you should be able to reach it from outside of `localhost`, provided you don't have firewalls and such blocking incoming traffic to that port.

Comment: Turns out I had to open port 8000 using iptables