# Web Server/Web service written in C++ in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, web-services, webserver

The requirement is to have Linux machine without additional installations aka Java, apache tomcat/jboss, that will be able to serve as a web server and to accept web service request (I will have to write some web service in C++ that will serve under this web server).

So, the question is if there is some C++ library that provides such a simulation of web server, since from outside it should behave the same way - to get http request and to redirect to appropriate web service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong place to ask ([softwarerecs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) is probably more appropriate), but you probably want to use some [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) server library like [libonion](http://www.coralbits.com/libonion/), or [libmongoose](http://cesanta.com/libmongoose.shtml), or even [Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt) etc. All these libraries enable adding some web serving abilities to your application (e.g. to code your Web server application in a few dozen of lines of C++).

<sup>BTW, if coding in Ocaml consider using [Ocsigen](http://ocsigen.org/) or Ocamlnet.</sup>

If you also want an HTTP client library, consider [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/)

You might also be interested in [fastcgi](http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/). Several existing web servers are able to handle some web requests to a [FastCGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI) application.

If you want to filter or transform HTTP requests, consider [ICAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Content_Adaptation_Protocol)

You need to be familiar with the basics of web technologies (HTTP, HTML5, Javascript, AJAX, Websockets, Jquery, ...) see e.g. [w3schools](http://w3schools.com/) (which is inperfect).

You might also need some database or indexed file library, like [sqlite](http://sqlite.org/) or [GDBM](http://www.gnu.org/s/gdbm)

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'll check the options. I need web server, actually. P.S. Why it is a wrong place?

Comment: The HTTP server libraries I mention enable you to write your own specialized web server in a few dozen of source lines.

Comment: Wrong place to ask, since your question is not related to your existing source code.

Comment: I'll mark your comment as an answer, although I'm going in another direction - gsoap. But your comment was the most informative. Libmongoose seems really impressive.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a very simple http server using node.js, answer copied from here:

[Using node.js as a simple web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084360/using-node-js-as-a-simple-web-server)

Simplest Node.js server is just:

```
$ npm install http-server -g
```

Now you can run a server via the following commands:

```
$ cd MyApp
$ http-server
```

Comment: true, however I understood the question as follows: 1. I need an http server (but not apache, tomcat with many dependencies) 2. from where webservices can be executed. Using the cgi interface, this is feasible with node.js + http

Answer (score 0):

To complement the other answers there's also:

**[Cutelyst](https://cutelyst.org)** a C++11 built with Qt, with one of the best positions on [TechEmpower Benchmarks](https://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/).

Even though it requires Qt 5.6+ a full CMS ([CMlyst](https://github.com/cutelyst/CMlyst)) uses around 6MB of RAM while serving around 3000 requests per seconds on a single core.