# how to get response from node.js in javascript by using ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, node.js

[screen shot of network panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMuiy.png)

[screen shot of console panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCrMo.png)

i want to send form details to node.js server by using ajax function i am able see in console whatever i am sending

But i am not able to get any response from node.js server to html ajax function

server.js

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function(request, response) {     
request.on('data', function (chunk) {   
    var res=chunk.toString('utf8');
    var obj=JSON.parse(res);
    var region=obj.region;
    var os=obj.os;              
    console.log(region);
    console.log(os);    
}); 
//var data="hi";
//how to send data
//response.send(data);
}).listen(8088);
```

client.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
function myFunction() { 
var region = document.getElementById("region").value;
var os = document.getElementById("os").value;  
var data = {};
data.region = region;
data.os = os;
$.ajax({
 type: 'POST',
 jsonpCallback: "callback",
 datatype: 'jsonp',
 data: JSON.stringify(data),
 //contentType: 'application/json',
 url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8088/', //node.js server is running
 success: function(data) {
   alert("success");
   console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
 },
 error: function (xhr, status, error){
    console.log('Failure');
    alert("failure");
    },
 });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="text" id="region" name="region"/>
<input type="text" id="os" name="os"/>
<input type="button" value="search" class="fil_search" onclick="myFunction()"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

help me out from this how get response from node.js server. just i want see the alert box of success message in html page

Comment: Add a screenshot from `Network` panel in your developer tools.

Comment: i am not able to attach the screen shot to this comment but the fallowing error i am getting " failure msg in alert box" and in console panel " XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1:8088/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access." i am getting this error

Comment: Attach screenshot to original post. You want help or not? If you do, can't you at least try to provide information for people to help you? I think it's the least you could do.

Comment: i have attached the screen shot of network panel and console panel pls check and give me the solution

Comment: Good job, I now know what caused your problem. You will have to follow one of the links I gave you - currently, it's impossible for XHR to work with your html and server.

Answer (score 1):

You should add request.on('end') event which will be fired when all data is received and http request is completed:

**data:** Is triggered whenever body data comes in at the TCP socket level. Note that this doesn’t necessarily contain all the data, hence it’s called a chunk.

**end:** Is triggered when the HTTP request is completed. This indicates that all body data associated with it was read and the appropriate data events have been triggered.

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(request, response) {     
  request.on('data', function (chunk) {  
    console.log("Received body data", chunk.toString());
    // chunk is received, process it as you need
  }); 
  request.on('end', function() {
    // http request is competed, send response to client
    response.writeHead(200, "OK", {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    response.end();
  })
}).listen(8088);
```

Comment: still i am not able to get any success alert

Comment: if i use get method i am able to alert the success message but i am not able see the data in console if i use post method i am getting error as 404 error

Comment: Have you made any changes suggested by Tomáš Zato (related to CORS)?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this happens to you is that you're loading the `127.0.0.1:8088` from a **`file://`** protocol. This is an insecure suspicious operation for the browser and it doesn't allow it in order to protect you.

You have two options now:

1. **[Enable CORS on your node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7067966/607407)** - let the node.js server tell your browser that it's ok to load requests from diferent domains.
2. **[Serve your `client2.html` from Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6084360/607407)** - instead of `file://`, you should get your `client2.html` from node js like from any other webserver - using URL path: `127.0.0.1:8088/client2.html`.

Links I have provided contain solutions to your problem, which is a [CORS error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). There is not solution without properly configuring your Node.js script.