# Node.js rendering either html or css, not both

Tags: html, css, node.js

Beginning my first node.js project and I'm finding that my code renders either the html with no styling, or the css code as plain text to the screen.  I open the page and see the html code, change nothing but hit refresh, and I see the css, and it switches back and forth every time I hit refresh. Can anyone tell me how to get it to apply the styling?  Thanks.  My code:

```
    http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    if(req.method.toLowerCase() == 'get'){

      fs.readFile('path\\to\\index.html', function (err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        res.write(data);
        //res.end();
      });

    }
    if(req.method.toLowerCase() == 'get'){

      fs.readFile('path\\to\\mystyle.css', function (err, data1) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/css'});
        res.write(data1);
        //res.end();
      });

    }

}).listen(4000, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:4000/');
```

The reason I have the 'res.end()'s commented out is that when I left either or both of them in, I got a 'write after end' error.  But I presume my problem is somewhere in that?

Edit: Just to add, I get the same problem if I remove both IF statements.  If I enclose both readFiles within the same IF statement, I get the 'write after end'.

Comment: You should add a conditional checking whether the requested file is the html or the css. At the moment, your code attempts to return both as response, in parallel... Have you considered using `express` or something similar to simplify this work?

Comment: See also: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8427954/1006854)

Comment: Thanks @mef, switch statement added and it works now, thanks.  I like doing things the hard way :)

Comment: @Meelah, you can answer your own question with the correct code, it might help other people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked in the end:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var formidable = require("formidable");
var util = require('util');
var url = require('url');

var html;
fs.readFile(__dirname+'\\index.html', function(err, data) {
    if (err){
        console.log(err);
        response.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    }
    html = data;
});

var css;
fs.readFile(__dirname+'\\mystyle.css', function(err, data) {
    if (err){
        console.log(err);
        response.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    }
    css = data;
});

var js;
fs.readFile(__dirname+'\\management.js', function(err, data) {
    if (err){
        console.log(err);
        response.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    }
    js = data;
});

var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    switch (request.url) {
        case "/mystyle.css" :
            response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/css"});
            response.write(css);
            break;
        case "/management.js" :
            response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/javascript"});
            response.write(js);
            break;
        default :    
            response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
            response.write(html);
    };
    response.end();
})
server.listen(4000);
console.log('server is listening at 4000');
```

You could easily put all the code inside the createServer function but the key is the switch.