# Load a kml file in locale (linux)

Tags: google-maps-api-3, laravel-5.1

Hy guys, I'm trying to load a KML file in path : "/var/www/laravel/public/kml/doc.kml" , but i can't.
The code of import is:

```
var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
      url: '/var/www/laravel/public/kml/doc.kml',
      map: map
    });
```

What I missed?

Answer (score 0):

loading KML formats are loaded like this (begins with http://):

url: 'http://kml-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/kml/Placemark/placemark.kml',

like

```
var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
     url: 'http://kml-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/kml/Placemark/placemark.kml',
     suppressInfoWindows: true,
     map: map
});
```

Your URL seems to be invalid: `/var/www/laravel/public/kml/doc.kml`

However, if you're running this map on a localhost, make sure you start your local [server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084360/using-node-js-as-a-simple-web-server) first.