# Node.js emits runtime error when listen to port 9999

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm completely new to nodeJs, and just to learn step by step. I managed to download, run nodeJs via the CMD and tested by creating file, all works fine. The problem now is when I want to tell nodeJs to display the output on the browser instead. I simply followed the tutorial but I'm getting runtime error. I suspect the port is somewhat wrong. Which port no I should use here, is it my localhost port which is 80, I tried it to no avail.

Here's the error message:
[image]

Referred here:[Using node.js as a simple web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084360/using-node-js-as-a-simple-web-server)

All I want is to be able to see the output in the browser via nodeJs. I think the port 9999 is meant for tcp connection as I'm learning for real-time app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using NodeJS to run your code. To run your code using NodeJS, run them with `node`:

`node c:\projects\test\helloweb.js`

The reason what you tried didn't work is that typing `c:\projects\test\helloweb.js` in cmd.exe and pressing Enter will not run the code in a browser, or in NodeJS. It will try to run it using whatever application you have associated with `.js` files. The Windows default, which is what your computer is using, is to use Windows Script Host (as you can see in your error message). WSH provides a runtime environment that's quite different from NodeJS and quite different from a browser.

Comment: @Keren "Worked with port 9999" is a strange comment... Do you understand why it wasn't working before?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, it wan't working before because I didn't type node before the filename...I mentioned port no because in my post I said I tested with localhost port..

Answer (score 1):

If you read the dialogue carefully you'll see its title is "Windows Script Host", not Node. In fact Node is a command-line tool that doesn't launch dialogues or other widgets. Your screenshot clearly shows you were doing it just fine and then eventually forgot to type `node` in your command:

[image: Annotated Screenshot]

FYI, Windows Script Host is a tool that's similar to Node (a server-side ECMAScript engine) but belongs to another vendor (Microsoft), uses a different ECMAScript implementation (JScript) and possibly hasn't been updated in 10 years. That means that features and available libraries are completely unrelated to those in Node.