# google api geolocation sample security error

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to show the map here by google map api in local environment.
I used the google api geolocation sample,

I have successfully showed the map in IE, but I could not show it in google chrome.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Geolocation</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
// Note: This example requires that you consent to location sharing when
// prompted by your browser. If you see the error "The Geolocation service
// failed.", it means you probably did not give permission for the browser to
// locate you.

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 6
  });
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});

  // Try HTML5 geolocation.
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var pos = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };

      infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
      infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
      map.setCenter(pos);
    }, function() {
      handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    });
  } else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
  }
}

function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
  infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
  infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                        'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                        'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
}

    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API KEY&signed_in=true&callback=initMap"
        async defer>
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I show you the error message below.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says it all. http and https protocols don't match. Try my procedure on how to runs these Map samples successfully. I am able to test every Map JS sample thanks to my local server.

**How to Run Any Google Map JS Sample in Local Environment**

1. Make sure you have Python installed in your computer.
2. Run [this command](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html) in your terminal :

   python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000

   *'Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...'* means you're local server is ready.
3. Go to Google Developer Console. Register `http://localhost:8000` as URL origin under the same API key credentials you're using. (It'll take at least 5 mins to take effect)
4. Run your google map file like `http://localhost:8000/geolocation.html` in the omnibox/address bar.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using a Google Chrome Browser version 50 or higher than that . And also you are trying to invoke the code from an HTTP url ,i.e http://192.168.33.10 . Google has removed access of Geo Location API from a non-secure resource since April 20 , 2016 starting from Chrome version 50.0 .So if you want to execute that code , your url should be https . Still, if you just want to test your code on the Chrome Browser for time being , use a Chrome Browser version less than 50.0 ,it should work fine for you. Here is the link to Google notification that announced this change https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only?hl=en . Please let me know if that helps you :) 
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. I  tried it like you said, but i could not be permitted to open the site for the security.  My friend uses a Google Chrome Browser version 51, and he can access it.

Comment: your friend could access it because may be he was hitting the url from localhost . Google does not consider "localhost" as unsecure. But since your url was like http://192.168.33.10 i thought you don't want to hit from localhost . I'm attaching snapshot of this statement from google's documentation in my updated answer.