# Having problems with enabling slack event

Tags: javascript, node.js, slack-api, ngrok

I opened a port on my PC using `ngrok`.

Was going to use the url given to enable events on my slack app.

I'm getting the following message on my terminal:

> `POST /slack/recieve`

and I'm also getting this on the slack page.:

> `Your URL didn't respond with the value of the challenge parameter.`

Below is the code I'm using (it's not my code. I'm doing the slackbot tutorial using botkit+node.js):

```
controller.hears(['^hello$'], 'direct_message,direct_mention', function(bot, message) {
  bot.reply(message, "Hi there, you're on workspace: " + message.team)
});
```

Comment: Things to check: 1. Do you have a webserver running on your local machine? Does it work to open a webpage through ngrok from your local machine? Does your app receive anything from Slack? (logfile)

Comment: this can not be the right code or that might be part of the problem. your app needs to reply with the challenge it receives from Slack.

Comment: thank you for your feedback. i'm not sure whether or not i have a local webserver running. i will look into all of this. It's been a great learning opportunity

Comment: If you have local webserver running and its setup correctly, just enter `localhost` in your browser. or the URL you got from ngrok. You should get the start page.

Comment: getting 
"Cannot GET /" when i enter localhost in my browser

Comment: Looks like you don't have a webserver running then. You can run a simple web server with node.js, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23122981/4379151

Comment: Or you can install a full WAMP stack: https://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/