# Javascript function not found in node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js

I followed this to set up the node.js server: [Using node.js as a simple web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084360/using-node-js-as-a-simple-web-server)

So I installed the serve-static npm.

I then created a file called file called test.html with the following code

```
<html>
<head>
  <h2>Google</h2>
</head>
<body>
  <button onclick="test()">Click me</button>
</body>
</html>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript">

  function test() {
    console.log('test');
  }

</script>
```

When I click on the button, I get:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (test.html:8)
```

and nothing else.  This code looks ok...? Why is this function not found?

Comment: Not only that, but you have to separate your external JS and your local one. Load jQuery in a `<script>` tag, and define your functions in another `<script>` tag.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to JS. I'm not following you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove your `src` part if you want to have your own function in between your `script` tags.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function test() {
    console.log('test');
  }
</script>
```

Also, you should put your scripts before your `</body>`

Comment: bullseye. Thanks!

Comment: @DaBlue you just cannot use the script body IF you use src

Answer (score 1):

Put your javascript just before closing body tag (`</body>`)

And in your case you are binding event handler in the html itself, in this case you have to define those functions before you use them.

In this case put `test()` function code in head tag. It will work fine

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript (script tag) is outside of html element. Put it in head or body.

Comment: I just did that and have the same issue.