# Ionic Creator exported, how to make database and server?

Tags: ionic-framework

So I am making a hybrid app and have used Ionic Creator to design the UI which I have now exported. So I now have an Ionic wrapper (I think) with all the pages and tabs linking nicely. However, no functionality e.g database. Please could someone tell me what to do next as I am very confused. Do I need to set up a server as well? And which is the best database solution to work with Ionic?

Thanks in advance. 
Not just a C dummy, also a web dummy

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You have to Set up Server by yourself.
you can use any Back-end Language for this e.g
1) Node.Js 
2) PHP
3) C#
4) Java
5) Python

For Nodejs see this Example [Nodejs Example Server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23122981/5909026)

Your can use Any data base of your choice. like MySql, Sql server, MongoDB or Firebase.

Comment: Thank you! I now have a basic express server. Could you advise me on the best way to add the database? I think I will use sqlite3

Comment: Check this npm package for sqlite3 and Nodejs.: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3
or you can use `MySql` check this also: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql