# how can i include css js in node js server

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var http = require("http");
var fs = require("fs");

var todo = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  fs.readFile("./todo.html", function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("no");
    } else {
      res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
      res.end(data);
    }
  });
});
todo.listen(3000);
```

here is my nodejs code i dont know how to include css js file . i cant include only html file. i want include css js file beacause  i want built web app by nodejs

Comment: Why don't you use some of nodejs frameworks like `Express`, `hapi`..etc

Answer (score 1):

You can include your css in `todo.html`

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">`

or for JavaScript

`<script src="scripts.js"></script>`

Comment: now i want practice only nodejs so is there any solution?

Comment: probably yes but is not that common, you can check some other solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084360/using-node-js-as-a-simple-web-server

Answer (score 0):

if you need to build a web application using nodejs it is recommended to using nodejs framework like `express.js` (https://expressjs.com/)
which already have basic building blocks to up and running quick web apps.
please refer express.js documentation for basic routing and serving static files to build a simple web application.
these are some starting guides

- https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html
- https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html

Comment: now i want a practice only node js is there any solution?