# Why I am getting a syntax Error in Node.js

Tags: html, node.js

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>NODE JS</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="">
    </head>

    <body>

        <h1>HALLO NODE JS</h1>
        <script src="./main.js" defer></script>

    </body>

</html>
```

NODE.JS

```
"use-strict";

const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const { error } = require('console');

const server = http.createServer((request, respone)=>{
    console.log(request.url, request.method);
    respone.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    fs.readFile('./index.html', (error, data)=>{
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
            respone.end();
        } else{
            respone.end(data);
        }
    });
    
});

server.listen(3000, 'localhost', ()=>{
    console.log("Wait for REQUEST FROM THE SERVER PORT ID 3000");
})
```

index.js

```
"use-strict";

document.querySelector("h1").addEventListener("click",()=>{console.log("H1 is CLICKED")});
```

I new begin to learn node.js
I try to get a respone from my server as a html-file. Now I always get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at main.js:1:1)", I do not understand why?

Comment: What is in main.js? If you have `<script></script>` remove them

Comment: when i removed the script it workd nice thanks

Comment: But how do i use the script  and add js-files in the html with node?

Comment: For now you do not even use or load index.js

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084360/using-node-js-as-a-simple-web-server