# Using less.js gives exception

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, less, tumblr

When I try to include `less.js` it gives me a **XmlHttpRequest Exception 101**.

I include the .less file like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="anything.less" />
```

Now, I'm working on a Tumblr theme, and this ONLY happens when I upload the theme to Tumblr.
Both files are included correctly, I can reach the real files by clicking the links in the source code.

Can anyone help me with this one?

I used this for production only. It's very time consuming to compile the less file locally, embed it into the template and then upload it again.

---

Not a duplicate of:

[LESS CSS minimal setup failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942277/less-css-minimal-setup-failure) 
I'm using Safari, and I'm using a global url (http://somelink.com/style.less).

Comment: is the less file located on the same domain as your html? less.js fetches the file via ajax

Comment: No not when I upload it to Tumblr. The html file is then on www.tumblr.com, and the .less file is on themelandia.com

Comment: @mkoryak Forgot to address you, look at my answer above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said:

> The html file is then on www.tumblr.com, and the .less file is on
>   themelandia.com

This means that less.js file must make a cross domain ajax request in order to retrieve your `.less` file. Browsers do not allow this, and thus the request fails.

If you want to fix your problem, you must put the `.less` file somewhere on tumblr.com

Comment: Won't be possible. The only way to do this is to upload it to tumblr static. I guess I'll have to do it the boring and time-consuming way. Thanks!