# @Import with client side less compilation

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, browser, less

I would like to create a bootstrap configuration page, rather like their own [customise bootstrap page](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/), but with live preview.

I want to therefore compile less files in the browser [as detailed in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10554462/how-can-i-compile-less-files-within-browser), but I don't know how to handle `@import`.

Usually, less knows the path of the files to import, but in the browser context, the file path model does not apply.

How can I compile less browser side, and use the @import feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="global.less">
<script src="js/less.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In the above `global.less` had been opened with a `XMLHttpRequest`, see also [How to open a local disk file with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582671/how-to-open-a-local-disk-file-with-javascript).

Files that you want to import in `global.less` with the `@import` directive can be places in the same directory `global.less`. Notice that this directory should be accessible by the browsers. Files can also be placed in a sub directory or a directory relative to the directory of `global.less`.

See also http://lesscss.org/usage/#using-less-in-the-browser you can set the option for the less.js compiler by defining a global `less` object before calling the compiler. This enables you to set the  `include_path` and `rootpath`, the `include_path` can be used to define where to search for the imports whilst the `rootpath`  re-write relative urls to the base less file.

NB For your live preview you should call `less.refreshStyles()` / `less.modifyVars`, see [ModifyVars issue when trying to change variables one by one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24997818/modifyvars-issue-when-trying-to-change-variables-one-by-one/25823551) unless reloading (and recompiling) is allowed.