# Less js modifyVars does not work with string path

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, less

i try to work with less js and available string path in less
with custom modifyvars
code

available.less

```
  @image-path : "/assets/images";

  @bg-image : "/bg/01.png";
```

style.less

```
  @import "available.less";

  body{
    background: url('@{image-path}@{bg-image}') repeat top left;
 }
```

in javascript

```
    less.modifyVars({
      '@bg-image' : "/bg/08.png"
     });
```

i get error ParseError: Unrecognised input

```
    @bg-image: /bg/08.png;
```

how to fix it

so if i change modifyVars to

```
    less.modifyVars({
     '@bg-image' : "'/bg/08.png'"
    });
```

with value wrap in double quote + single qoute it work ! but i dont need this fix because modifyVars i'm get form html element by jquery

Comment: why not wrap your input from the form element in quotes if that works?

Comment: my element too much , like color , fontsize ... so when i wrap all this value in my function then bg image modifyvars work so , whit color , font size ex... not work , i think only need wrap input as string or path ! can you give me some solution to do this @PatrickGunderson

Comment: You need to escape the strings that come from your html form using "escapeURIComponent"

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: escapeURIComponent is not defined @PatrickGunderson  when i using encodeURIComponent i get http://localhost:8080/project/asset/images%2Fbg%2F02.png not found 
http://localhost:8080/project/asset/images/bg/02.png right path ? another solution

Answer (score 1):

Consider to add quotes around your string only when it is a URL. You can test your string for having a `/`:

```
if(field.value.indexOf("/") !== -1) {
          variables['@' + field.name] = '"' + field.value + '"';
}
```

See also: [ModifyVars issue when trying to change variables one by one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24997818/modifyvars-issue-when-trying-to-change-variables-one-by-one/25823551)