# Is LESS compatible with chrome15?

Tags: google-chrome, less

I'm exploring less/sass tools and I have difficulties to have a clear picture. My first question, is LESS compatible with chrome15/where can I find a table of compatibilities.

Comment: is LESS compatible with chrome 15 is too broad ? seriously ?

Comment: Your original question was certainly too broad + asking for an off-site resource.  Now you're just asking for an off-site resource.  This is an extremely low-effort question.

Comment: I'm asking is less compatible with chrome15, if this question is that obvious please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome or any browser for that matter never sees your LESS files. Ideally, your files would have compiled to CSS before the browser ever sees it.

Comment: on the less documentation it's written it can work browser side, meaning you compile it browser side isn't it ? then will it work with any browser version ?

Comment: That functionality is not native on the browser. What you end up doing is compiling your less script at runtime using js. I personally can't think of an instance where this is recommended above compiling during build. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10554462/how-can-i-compile-less-files-within-browser