# have NETWORK_ERR with less.js

Tags: javascript, css, less

I'm using less.js for better responsive css design, but now I encounter NETWORK_ERR while using webkit based browser and also chrome. However firefox would not have this kinda issue.

I trying to google my question but it seems the only solution is to put less files on other server or it's unavoidable to read less.js' src as "file:**///**xxxx/less.js" instead of "file:***//*xxxx/less.js" .

My question is , is there any way to do to change the way as file:/// to file://?

and one more question , is there any better css framework which can do better responsive and organized design? Less.js is good to organize and I also use javascript to change some variable dynamic.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always good to serve css js and images from a different server which can act as CDN. and in your case you can also over come the chrome issue.

here are some of the solutions for your file:/// to file:// issue (not sure if you have already seen these)

look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084892/less-js-not-working-in-chrome)

you can over come this in couple of ways look at Nathan Strutz's answer where he is suggesting to add a command-line switch -allow-file-access-from-files to your shortcut and Chrome will allow you to load LESS.JS without any problem, and also below you can how to add the command line switch.

also i am particularly interested in MrClean's answer (last answer) I havent tried it out though but you can give it a try.

and to answer your second question there are bunch of frameworks which can do css responsive designes [click here](http://speckyboy.com/2011/11/17/15-responsive-css-frameworks-worth-considering/) for list i am particularly interested in foundation, mqframework, Golden Grid System framework and Fluid Baseline Grid.

Comment: I agree with most of people's advise : to build a web server . Chrome -allow-file-access-from-files seems work for me . but what McClean's answer doesn't , ha.

Comment: I already tried some famous responsive css framework. but my client device may differ with many kind of size , not only common ones. I hope not only set maximum or min . Instead , all the fontSize or margin ,image size will change dynamic by screen size.

Comment: @George in that case you may have to use Javascript to render height and fonts.

Comment: yes ,I know . in the beginning, I use js to control all width/height/font/margin....etc dynamically , but I also need to control my css file . That's why I use less.js to control them all...