# LESS CSS not working locally

Tags: css, less

I really want to learn LESS but have had NO luck getting it to work at all. I would like to get it to work locally. Please help.

I just want to do a simple test. 
Here is my LESS code:

```
@color: red;

.header {
    color: @color;
}

h2 {
    color: @color;
}
```

And here is my HTML code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>LESS TEST</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="style.less">
    <script src="less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="header"> <h2>This is a test</h2> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So the header class should be red and also the H2 should be red. But they do not display with any styling on any browser. 
Please help!

Comment: Are you sure the `style.less` file is in the same folder as your HTML page?

Comment: And if you're on Windows, you can use winless http://winless.org/ I would definitly go for precompiling!

Comment: try use the google hosted file. <script src="http://lesscss.googlecode.com/files/less-1.3.0.min.js"></script>

Comment: [This](http://lesscss.org/#client-side-usage) will help. Make sure to link the all the stylesheets before linking `less.js`. Have you checked the JavaScript console? On Chrome, go to the webpage and click `Ctrl + Shift + J`

Answer (score 4):

Your code works perfectly, as shown in this screenshot:

[image]

Note that I downloaded a minified version of [less.js](http://lesscss.org/2.5.3/dist/less.min.js) locally prior to running this. I suggest you verify:

1. that your files are properly named and located: check for 404 errors in your web console (F12 in Chrome and Firefox).
2. that your files are being served by a webserver. Less files will not be served if you try to access them through at a `file:///path/less.js` URL -- Chrome gives me a "cross origin request" error.

Comment: Cross origin requests can be solved through sending Access-control headers. Using a CDN should work fine.

Comment: @ytpillai you're absolutely right. But I guess the OP is serving the static files from the filesystem.

Comment: @RégisB., in my application every thing are working but style.less CSS file is not showing in console when I am doing inspect element. Please help me.

Comment: @IshimdarAhamad this looks like a different problem. Please create a new question.

Comment: @RégisB., can you give me your email, I will send a small application.

Answer (score 2):

Disable cache in Chrome, worked in my case.

[image: Disable cache in Chrome]

Answer (score 1):

I use [WINLESS](http://winless.org/). It's free, it's easy to use and very powerful on minifying the code.

- Download, install and open Winless;
- Open the LESS file with the
  compliler and keep in mind that every time you save the LESS file,
  Winless will compile it into a CSS file;
- Include the CSS file that result into your header.

You don't have to emulate an Apache server to use it.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Windows Sever Add Mime Type Less or web.config file add line

```
        <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".less" mimeType="text/css" />
    </staticContent>

       <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css" media="all" />
    <link href="http://www.petshop.net.tr/less-ornek/stil.less" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet/less" media="all" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="less-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using chrome, take a look at this:

[less.js not working in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084892/less-js-not-working-in-chrome)

in short:

> Less.js browser script currently won’t work if you’re using Chrome and
>   the path to your page starts with “file:///” due to a known Chrome
>   issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a server to run the code. 
A simple way to run the code on MAC is using the python server

Do the following ,in terminal locate the folder containing the code then type in `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000`. in browser go to localhost:8000