# Less not compiling to CSS

Tags: html, css, less

I am using [less.js to compile less on the fly](http://lesscss.org/usage/#using-less-in-the-browser). Here's a sample of my markup:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet/less" href="sample.less" type="text/css" />
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/1.7.4/less.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="box">
            abcd
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It is not compiling less into CSS:

[image: screenshot showing undesired results]

Comment: I've been using Prepros and I love it.

http://alphapixels.com/prepros/

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18531239

Comment: possible duplicate of [less.js not working in chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084892/less-js-not-working-in-chrome)

Answer (score -1):

In order to compile LESS to CSS, you should use lessc command in terminal if you're not using any task managers.

Navigate to your directory on terminal and type this command.

$ lessc path/styles.less > path/styles.css

Once this is run, refresh your browser. LESS should be converted to CSS.

Please follow http://lesscss.org/ under using "Using LESS"

Comment: The very first line of the question: "I am using less.js to compile less on the fly"...

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways to fix this

1] **Use Firefox** instead of chrome as this is a known issue for chrome.

2]Run your files on any server like **Apache,IIS.**