# LESS styling not working

Tags: javascript, css, less

I am using `style.less` in my page for testing purpose but when i run it in browser using file protocol I am getting below exception

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/Desktop/Web/less_sample/style/style.less. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

but when i run the same in localhost it is working.
can somebody explain why it is so even though i have `less.js`in both the case?
thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to convert to CSS file. The browser not read css preprocessor files. Edit: "In both case" sorry. Maybe problem is in the `file:///`.

Comment: less.js allows browser/client side compiling of the less file

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084892; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18529733

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Less requires to be running on a server to work. So when you are accessing it through the `file://` protocol, it can not be processed. Using localhost means you are accessing it through the local server, and therefore the files can be processed.

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all

When you are using localhost, you are using http:// and not file://