# LESS client side

Tags: javascript, less

I'm trying to get this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andsens/d7vKd/) to work locally. It does not render properly. I've no idea why. The linked .less file is copied directly from the fiddle. The result of my markup is a blank page. I opted to use the CDN because when I downloaded the [source](http://lesscss.org/#client-side-usage) I was unsure which less.js file to copy.

Here's the markup:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>radial-progress</title>
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles/radial-progress.less">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/2.5.1/less.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body>
    <div class="radial-progress" data-progress="0">
        <div class="circle">
            <div class="mask full">
                <div class="fill"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="mask half">
                <div class="fill"></div>
                <div class="fill fix"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="shadow"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="inset">
            <div class="percentage"></div>
        </div>
</div>
<script>
$('head style[type="text/css"]').attr('type', 'text/less');
less.refreshStyles();
window.randomize = function() {
$('.radial-progress').attr('data-progress', Math.floor(95));}
    setTimeout(window.randomize, 200);
    $('.radial-progress').click(window.randomize);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: locally as on a local server or as on the file protocol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is you are running off the C: drive instead of a local server so the relative protocol link is breaking.

```
src="//cdnjs..."
```

needs to be

```
src="http://cdnjs..."
```

Better yet look into running your own server. It is simple with [python](http://www.tecmint.com/python-simplehttpserver-to-create-webserver-or-serve-files-instantly/) or [node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333790/node-js-quick-file-server-static-files-over-http).

Comment: Is it not possible to run through the file protocol?

Comment: You can run on file protocol, but it is a bad idea. The file protocol has different browser restrictions than the web and will make your job a nightmare.

Comment: I made the change you suggesting; nothing changed. I'll research running with python or node

Comment: Error in the developer console?

Comment: unsure of your question; I've never used a developer console. This is my first attempt

Comment: **Developer Tools:** [Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console) or [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console) or [IE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565625(v=vs.85).aspx) or [Safari](https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/)

Comment: plenty, apparently this is only an issue on chrome .. it partially works in ff, I'm still unable to get the transition to show

Comment: @Ayaz It's [possible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18529733) to use file protocol in Chrome too. Aditionally note that you don't need `$('head style[type="text/css"]').attr('type', 'text/less'); less.refreshStyles();` stuff, it's used only to hack jsfiddle to compile it's css code as less one.