# Error when trying to use LESS on file://

Tags: css, google-chrome, less

When I try to use my LESS file on google chrome it brings up this error on console:

```
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
less.js:446 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///path/core.less. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
```

I have downloaded the less.js and put it in the script tags as seen below

```
head class="Setup">
    <!-- LESS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="path/core.less"/>
    <script src="path/less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

However if I use a package for my text editor, namely https://atom.io/packages/browser-plus it works fine. Console logs:

```
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
less.js:837 rendered file:///path/core.less successfully.
less.js:837 css for file:///path/core.less generated in 67ms
less.js:837 less has finished. css generated in 67ms
```

After checking the Google Chrome versions, the text editor uses Version 47 whereas my normal chrome is on Version 50. I have no idea what's happening. Is there a fix for this?

EDIT: Found [less.js not working in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084892/less-js-not-working-in-chrome/7350858#7350858)
Since I don't know how to setup Apache I tried searching up how to create command-line switches brought up windows results whereas I'm using a mac.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18529733 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084892.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've correctly identified, LESS.js won't work with the `file://` URL scheme in Chrome:

> P.S.S. Less.js browser script currently won’t work if you’re using
>   Chrome and the path to your page starts with “file:///” due to a known
>   Chrome issue.

Since you're running Mac OSX, I'd advise installing MAMP, since it takes the headache out of setting up a local server for you:

https://www.mamp.info/en/

Comment: Thanks! I never knew MAMP existed and it saves a lot of would be effort for me set up Apache when I didn't know how to even with the docs if there were no alternatives.